# jQuery AJAX PHP OOP Login Loses SESSION after login

Tags: php, jquery

I have an object oriented PHP login system that logs in the user sucessfully using jQuery AJAX, but upon redirection the a new web page (or the return URL), the $SESSION information is lost. What is wrong with the coding?

**EDIT/UPDATE:** I found this issue occurs on any page when I assign or view / echo a $_SESSION variable. Something is not right. This is a copy of my php.ini file for SESSIONS.

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
;
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"

; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies = 1

; http://php.net/session.cookie-secure
;session.cookie_secure =

; This option forces PHP to fetch and use a cookie for storing and maintaining
; the session id. We encourage this operation as it's very helpful in combating
; session hijacking when not specifying and managing your own session id. It is
; not the end all be all of session hijacking defense, but it's a good start.
; http://php.net/session.use-only-cookies
session.use_only_cookies = 1

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start = 1

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

; The path for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-path
session.cookie_path = /

; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-domain
session.cookie_domain =

; Whether or not to add the httpOnly flag to the cookie, which makes it inaccessible to browser scripting languages such as JavaScript.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-httponly
session.cookie_httponly =

; Handler used to serialize data.  php is the standard serializer of PHP.
; http://php.net/session.serialize-handler
session.serialize_handler = php

; Defines the probability that the 'garbage collection' process is started
; on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using
; gc_probability/gc_divisor. Where session.gc_probability is the numerator
; and gc_divisor is the denominator in the equation. Setting this value to 1
; when the session.gc_divisor value is 100 will give you approximately a 1% chance
; the gc will run on any give request.
; Default Value: 1
; Development Value: 1
; Production Value: 1
; http://php.net/session.gc-probability
session.gc_probability = 1

; Defines the probability that the 'garbage collection' process is started on every
; session initialization. The probability is calculated by using the following equation:
; gc_probability/gc_divisor. Where session.gc_probability is the numerator and
; session.gc_divisor is the denominator in the equation. Setting this value to 1
; when the session.gc_divisor value is 100 will give you approximately a 1% chance
; the gc will run on any give request. Increasing this value to 1000 will give you
; a 0.1% chance the gc will run on any give request. For high volume production servers,
; this is a more efficient approach.
; Default Value: 100
; Development Value: 1000
; Production Value: 1000
; http://php.net/session.gc-divisor
session.gc_divisor = 1000

; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; NOTE: If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
;       happen automatically.  You will need to do your own garbage
;       collection through a shell script, cron entry, or some other method.
;       For example, the following script would is the equivalent of
;       setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
;          find /path/to/sessions -cmin +24 | xargs rm

; PHP 4.2 and less have an undocumented feature/bug that allows you to
; to initialize a session variable in the global scope, even when register_globals
; is disabled.  PHP 4.3 and later will warn you, if this feature is used.
; You can disable the feature and the warning separately. At this time,
; the warning is only displayed, if bug_compat_42 is enabled. This feature
; introduces some serious security problems if not handled correctly. It's
; recommended that you do not use this feature on production servers. But you
; should enable this on development servers and enable the warning as well. If you
; do not enable the feature on development servers, you won't be warned when it's
; used and debugging errors caused by this can be difficult to track down.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/session.bug-compat-42
session.bug_compat_42 = Off

; This setting controls whether or not you are warned by PHP when initializing a
; session value into the global space. session.bug_compat_42 must be enabled before
; these warnings can be issued by PHP. See the directive above for more information.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/session.bug-compat-warn
session.bug_compat_warn = Off

; Check HTTP Referer to invalidate externally stored URLs containing ids.
; HTTP_REFERER has to contain this substring for the session to be
; considered as valid.
; http://php.net/session.referer-check
session.referer_check =

; How many bytes to read from the file.
; http://php.net/session.entropy-length
session.entropy_length = 0

; Specified here to create the session id.
; http://php.net/session.entropy-file
; On systems that don't have /dev/urandom /dev/arandom can be used
; On windows, setting the entropy_length setting will activate the 
; Windows random source (using the CryptoAPI)
session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom

; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
; http://php.net/session.cache-limiter
session.cache_limiter = nocache

; Document expires after n minutes.
; http://php.net/session.cache-expire
session.cache_expire = 180

; trans sid support is disabled by default.
; Use of trans sid may risk your users security.
; Use this option with caution.
; - User may send URL contains active session ID
;   to other person via. email/irc/etc.
; - URL that contains active session ID may be stored
;   in publicly accessible computer.
; - User may access your site with the same session ID
;   always using URL stored in browser's history or bookmarks.
; http://php.net/session.use-trans-sid
session.use_trans_sid = 1

; Select a hash function for use in generating session ids.
; Possible Values
;   0  (MD5 128 bits)
;   1  (SHA-1 160 bits)
; This option may also be set to the name of any hash function supported by
; the hash extension. A list of available hashes is returned by the hash_algos()
; function.
; http://php.net/session.hash-function
session.hash_function = 0

; Define how many bits are stored in each character when converting
; the binary hash data to something readable.
; Possible values:
;   4  (4 bits: 0-9, a-f)
;   5  (5 bits: 0-9, a-v)
;   6  (6 bits: 0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", ",")
; Default Value: 4
; Development Value: 5
; Production Value: 5
; http://php.net/session.hash-bits-per-character
session.hash_bits_per_character = 4

; The URL rewriter will look for URLs in a defined set of HTML tags.
; form/fieldset are special; if you include them here, the rewriter will
; add a hidden <input> field with the info which is otherwise appended
; to URLs.  If you want XHTML conformity, remove the form entry.
; Note that all valid entries require a "=", even if no value follows.
; Default Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset="
; Development Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
; Production Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
; http://php.net/url-rewriter.tags
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="
```

I have the initial log in page login. php (that also contains the jQuery AJAX)
login.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fluxexchange.com/fluxexchange/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" id="login" class="network_login" onSubmit="return false;">
                                <h3>Sign in to share your cultures and interests with friends.</h3>
                                <div>
                                <label>Handle, Email, or Phone</label><input name="handle" id="login-handle" class="login_input">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <label>Passcode</label><input name="password" id="login-password" class="login_input" type="password">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <input class="auto-authenticate" type="checkbox" style="border:0px;"><label style="width:auto;">Keep me authenticated</label>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                    $iredirect_url=$_GET['return_url'];
                                ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $iredirect_url; ?>">

                                <label id="login_submit_button" class="login_button">
                                    <input class="login-button-blue" value="Authenticate" type="submit">
                                </label>
                                <div id="login-loader" class="loader"></div>
                                <span class="login-option" id="more-login-options">I'm looking for more login options.</span>
                            </form>
              $(function(){
    $("#login-loader").hide();
    $("#login-success-notification").hide();
    $("#login_submit_button").click(function(){
        $("#login-loader").fadeIn(1000);
        authenticateUser();
    });
});
function authenticateUser(){

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"engine/authenticate_user.php",
        cache:false,
        data: $("#login").serialize(),
        dataType:"json",
        async:false,
        success: function(resp){

            console.log(resp);

            $('.reg-error-notification').empty();
            $('.reg-error-notification').hide();


            if(resp.logged_in=="true"){
                $("#login-success-notification").append('<p>'+resp.session_test+'</p>').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    window.location.href=resp.return_url;
                });

            } else {
                $("#login-loader").fadeOut(1000);
                $('#login-error-notification').append('<p>The handle you entered is incorrect. Please try again.</p>').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        },
    });
}
    </body>
</html>
```

and index.php (where the login was redirected to when the issue occurred.

```
<?
    session_start();
        print_r($_SESSION['network_id']);   

?>
```

and authenticate_user.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("login-classes.php");

    $Authenticate= new Authenticate($_POST['handle'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['network'], $_POST['fenetwork']);
    $Authenticate->authenticateUser();

    $result=array();
    if($Authenticate->isLoggedIn()){

        $result['logged_in']="true";
        $result['return_url']=($_POST['return_url']);
        $result['session_test']=$_SESSION['network_id'];
    } else {

        $result['logged_in']="false";
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

login-classes.php (included in authenticate_user.php)

```
 <?php
        //(C) Flux Exchange Network, Inc.
        require ("database-classes.php");

        class Authenticate {

            public function __construct($username, $password, $network_site, $parent_network) {

                $this->handle=$username;
                $this->password=crypt($password, $this->salt);
                $this->parent_network=$parent_network;
                $this->network_site=$network_site;          
            }

            public function authenticateUser(){
                $database=new Database();
                $database->getConnection();
                $database->startConnection();

                $authenticate_q=mysql_query("SELECT network_users.network_id
                FROM network_users
                WHERE network_users.handle = '$this->handle'
                AND network_users.password ='$this->password'
                LIMIT 1");

                if(mysql_num_rows($authenticate_q)==1){

                    $this->isLoggedIn=true;
                    $user=mysql_fetch_array($authenticate_q);
                    $this->network_id=$user['network_id'];
                    $this->setNetworkId();
                } else{
                    //header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
                    //die("Something went wrong.");
                }
            }

            function isLoggedIn(){

                return $this->isLoggedIn;
            }

            function addError($error){

                $this->error_list[]=$error;
            }


            function setNetworkId(){

                $_SESSION['network_id']=$this->network_id;
            }

            private $network_id, $handle, $password, $network_site, $parent_network, $error_list, $isLoggedIn=false,
            $salt="PRIVATE INFO";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: For starters, use your browser tools to look at the network traffic and inspect the request/response headers. Check if the cookie is being handed around correctly.

Comment: @Charles: I'm using Google Chrome. I'm not sure on how to look for request / response headers. But, what I did see was 200 OKs as responses under "Network". Also under cookies there is a PHPSESSID with the value of a long string of characters. I have my php script echo or json back to the ajax the user_id and it displays so I know for sure that the SESSION is initialized. It's when it redirects back to index.php that there is a problem.

Comment: Are you sanitising your input before using it in an SQL query?

Comment: Click on the file name of those requests you see, then look at the headers.

Comment: @Alex: No, I have not. The security I am concerned about after doing test runs to make sure the script works.

Comment: @deceze I'm using Google Chrome, and the Cookie says PHPSESSID=51988711cfcca91750b2d5746a24cdf1. What's more interesting though is that under the Headers section it says Response Headers expires Nov 19 1981. That's odd. haha.

Comment: And is the cookie being transferred correctly? Is the server ever responding with a new cookie at any point? Track it.

Comment: @deceze: Not it's not. The cookie has the same value every time when I am checking it in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's a problem with your PHP configuration.

I had this problem a few days ago on my linux test machine - I solved it simply by clearing the contents of /tmp - where session data is stored.

What version of PHP are you running?

For older versions of PHP there is an extension session.so (in php.ini) that must be enabled for it work, on newer versions it should work by default.

You can check the path where session data is saved in your php.ini file, search for the line

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

On newer installations this is commented out, which is fine as it defaults to /tmp.

Make sure that permissions are set correctly for PHP to read/write to the folder.

Comment: When I look in my php.ini file it says: session.save_path = "N;/path" is that right? It doesn't look right to me. haha

Comment: I have updated this question/post to show you the complete SESSION section of my php.ini file.

Comment: So it's set as /var/php_sessions - check that the directory exists and chmod it to 777 EDIT - and also delete everything in that directory.

Comment: I just found out the problem is my hosting service. They have fixed the problem on their end, and now it works.

Comment: I have provided a vote up and your answer as the resolution since you were right about the PHP configuration.

Comment: The path did not exist and that is what the issue was. haha.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a silly question - but are your login files on the same domain?
PHP sessions won't transfer across subdomains, so if your login.php is on a subdomain eg. login.example.com and your index.php is on www.example.com - this won't work..

Comment: They are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested that PHP sessions are working?

The reason I ask is that I recently did a fresh install of linux / apache / PHP - and my sessions didn't work until I deleted the contents of /tmp

Can test by creating 2 files, file 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']='hi';
```

file2:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: I just had some success a few moments ago. I added the code setcookie('user_id', $userid); in place of $_SESSION['network_id']=$this->network_id; in the setNetworkId() function of login-classes.php. When I check the browser's console it reflects that a cookie was created with the name network_id and the correct value for the user_id. What do you think may have occurred? haha.

Comment: Sounds like sessions aren't working! Not so good to use setcookie as it won't work for anyone with cookies disabled.. Did you try the test?

Comment: I created a test session on index.php, and it printed successfully. So something is wrong between the authentication at authenticate_user.php (which is done by jQuery AJAX at login.php, and index.php when the SESSION is set to echo or display. I have no clue what it is though.

Comment: It will always work on a single page, did you test setting a session on one page and retrieving it on a different one?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, and it's not passing from page to page. I created a S_SESSION['test'] on one page, and echo on the other and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now narrowed down to a $_SESSION variable going from page to page. I have ensured that all pages have session_start() at the top and have set the session and echo'd the session on the separate page. However, it is not carrying the data to the next page. What are the possible causes for this?